# How can I create a column for cumulative count in Power BI?

Tags: timestamp, powerbi, dax, powerquery, cumulative-frequency

I am trying to create a new column in a table like the last column here:
[image]

Where I can count up the cumulative products **from the same category** that are added to a basket, based on the timestamp. I've tried grouping and adding an index column, but the timestamps are really important (as seen in rows 7 and 8), where I want the count to reset as they are not consecutive to the other products in category 1 (Cat1).

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi, I think that adding an index is a good solution. But you will need to compare the row above, in order to spot differences/switch from category to category. I would add a costum column somewhat close to `if #"Added Index"{[Index] +1} [Product Category] and #"Added Index"{[Index]} [Product Category] <> null then #"Added Index"{[Index]+1} = "New Category" else "same category"` I have not tested this however.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a definitive solution, but I hope that this is a perspective nonetheless:

What seems important to me in your file, more than the "added to Baket Timestamp" column is the continutiy of item purchases.

Thus, each time a Category appears and replace another, an new seperate index should be created.

I tried to more in that direction, but I do not have the full solution yet. I really hope that the following steps can be usefull nonethless:

```
  AddedIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Promoted Headers", "Index", 0, 1),
    //This adds your index
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(AddedIndex, "Compare", each if AddedIndex{[Index]}[Product Category] <> AddedIndex{[Index]-1}[Product Category] then "category change" else "same category"),
     //This compares the row above in the "Product Category" column and the row below, in order to spot whenever we get a "change" in our sequence.
     // I get an error however for my the first row, because an "Index" cannot be negative. I do not know how to solve this issue yet.
    #"Added Conditional Column1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", each if [Compare] = "category change" then 0 else {[Index]+1})
in
    #"Added Conditional Column1"
     //In this last step I was aiming to either create a "local" index each time there is varaition between "same category" and "category change" or keep adding one but I encounter the following error: "we cannot appliy field acces to the type list"
```